# Download file from URL fails with error 500

Tags: powershell

What I want to do is to write an automatic script which will download everyday a file and save it on a server.
First problem I met is the form of the URL which is not `website.com/file.zip` but rather `http://www.website.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=8pIcfhrhw%3d&tabid=900&mid=85`.
I did a test with PowerShell and I have the following mistake:

```
Exception lors de l'appel de « DownloadFile » avec « 2 » argument(s) :
« The remote server returned an error : (500) Internal Server Error. »
At the level of C:\Users\me\test.ps1 : 5 Caractère : 24
+ $webclient.DownloadFile <<<< ($url, $file)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

If you can help me with batch I take it too. I work on Windows not Linux.

My script:

```
$storageDir = $pwd
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://www.website.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=8pIcfhrhw%3d&tabid=900&mid=85"
$file = "$storageDir\newdata.pdf"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url, $file)
```

Comment: The problem is on the server side. Check that the URL is correct. Also check the server logs.

Comment: The url i gave is an exemple not the real one. I wanted to show you the format of the url and know if there is a way to use it for my download

Comment: AFAICS there's nothing inherently wrong with the URL, but only the server knows what it will accept, so you need to check there.